# Why does the error, "An exception was thrown by the target on an invocation" appear when running MessagingCenter.Send?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

When the project runs `MessagingCenter.Send`, it throws the error, "An exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

This error appeared the first time I deployed my project after restarting Visual Studio, and I had not changed the code inside of the `MessagingCenter.Subscribe` method since the last deployment.

How do I view what this exception is?
Edit: [I couldn't copy the call stack normally, so here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONAYW.png)

Comment: look at the InnerException property of the exception object and it's stack trace

Comment: please post the exception stack trace

Comment: @zafar How can I copy the stack trace?

Comment: @PurpleSprinkles Wrap the call inside the `try` block and catch it inside catch block `catch(Exception ex)` then print `Console.WriteLine(ex)`, you should be able to see the full stack trace in the output window of the VS

Comment: @zafar After putting the call inside the ```try``` block it doesn't raise an exception.

Comment: @zafar I got to the stack trace through the call stack window, I was able to screenshot it. It's in the edit on the post

Comment: Does this project works well before? if not, could do you provide the code for us to reproduce.

Comment: @PurpleSprinkles your stack trace does not include the inner exception details. Inner exception will give an idea as to why exactly it is happening. When the debugger breaks after an unhandled exception, hit continue, and you should be able to see all that information in the output pane of the VisualStudio (use Ctrl+Alt+O to view the output panel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By commenting out some code, I figured out what the problem was.

The true error was that I was trying to edit the index of a list that was out of range. The list gets its items from a file in Internal Storage, so that file was either corrupted or reset somehow, and the list was reset with it.

It's an easy fix, and had I known that `MessagingCenter.Subscribe` will trace back an exception to `MessagingCenter.Send`, I wouldn't have asked this question.